# Shield UI Editor Custom Tools

Tags: editor, rich-text-editor, shieldui

Does ShieldUI Editor support implementing custom tools like buttons for triggering events and manipulating the edited content?

I need to implement a syntax-checking utility for a side project and will need to add my own button.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the functionality is supported. You can check the following demo for more details:
http://demos.shieldui.com/web/editor/custom-commands